# How git syncs two or more Pull requests commit history?

Tags: git, github

Let's say we have a project "makeCake" as our remote:origin

My friend and I both are working on improvements for this cake project. We both do the following -

`git clone makeCake`

`git checkout -b selfName/new_feature`

`git push set upstream selfName/new_feature`

`git add changedfilename`

`git commit -m "some message"`

`git fetch origin master:master`

`git rebase -i master`

and

`git push`

Then we both open individual PRs for makeCake. What saves our PRs from overwriting each other changes while they are being pulled into makeCake?

Comment: Note that Git itself does not have Pull Requests; these are a GitHub add-on. (They exist in Bitbucket as well but are slightly different there. They exist in GitLab but are so different *there* that they're not called "pull requests" in the first place.) But none of this matters to your most basic question, which is: how does distributed, collaborative work actually *work* in a distributed version control system, and that's a fairly large question.

Comment: The way Git specifically does this is that nobody is working on "the" files. There are no "the" files. Everyone is working locally on a *copy* they have extracted from a *commit*. They make new commits, which are full snapshots of every file. Later, people merge commits, or use "rebase" to copy commits to new-and-improved commits. This converts snapshots into changes if and when necessary and appropriate, and *combines* changes if and when appropriate, to get the effect of *combining work*. The results go into yet more commits; the existing commits are never touched once they exist.

Comment: The effect is that you have an ever-growing mass of *commits*. With some optional exceptions (that in general need to be agreed-to in advance by everyone who will be affected), nobody's commits ever go away. If something's wrong in some commit, you add another commit in which the wrong thing is corrected. By only ever *adding new commits*, everyone can grab everyone else's commits and add them to their repositories. Using `git rebase` results in *discarding* existing commits in favor of new-and-improved ones, and this gets tricky if someone else has grabbed the old ones; as a result [cont'd]

Comment: [continued] rebase must be used very carefully. One rule some use is "only rebase commits nobody else has seen", which solves the "someone else got them already" problem. Others (more advanced users, e.g., the guys who develop Git) use a rule where certain branch names are known to behave this way, and it's your fault if you mis-use the commits you can find on these branches. (But that gets pretty hairy.)